# NMAP scanning through TOR

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, whonix

I have configured my  Kali Linux  (VM) through Whonix Gateway 13 and it's working, But when I do scans the results are unbelievable for an example I scanned my own network I have only open a few ports but the scans results show about hundreds of open ports even the OS scans are wrong.

Comment: **Please do not portscan over Tor**. Portscans are noisey and obvious and result in abuse reports that exit operators have to deal with. There are smarter ways to approach this _(including only portscanning systems that you are authorised to scan)_.